# Whitespace is listed as a child node but text is not

Tags: javascript, dom

newlines in my code are listed as child nodes (I already found online that this is normal), so that the following element actually has 5 child nodes, 3 of them are the whitespaces:

```
<tbody id="test">
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>   
</tbody>
```

If I code it all in one line this problem goes away.

Another weird way to make it go away is to put some actual text there, and for some reason it doesn't register in the DOM at all. For example the following element only has 2 children (the table rows):

```
<tbody id="test">x
    <tr></tr>x
    <tr></tr>x  
</tbody>
```

Can someone explain why this is?

Comment: *"If I code it all in one line this problem goes away."* What makes it a "problem"? *(not my downvote, btw, seems harsh to me)*

Comment: Thanks :) It seems like a problem because it requires special attention when I iterate over the table rows. I dealt with it but I didn't understand why it should be there.

Comment: On any vaguely-modern browser, you can use the [`children`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-children) collection (rather than [`childNodes`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-childnodes)), which only contains elements (not other kinds of nodes). Specifically for tables/thead/tbody/tfoot, you can use the [`rows`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#dom-tbody-rows) collection as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you've put text in a place where it cannot appear: As a direct child of the `tbody` element. Since that's invalid, the browser relocates it. It won't be left out, but you'll find it either before or after the table (depending on the browser; when faced with invalid HTML, the browser can do whatever it likes).

Chrome puts it before the table, for instance:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="test">x
      <tr></tr>x
      <tr></tr>x  
  </tbody> 
</table>
```